# Center images in a 2 column layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm working with XHTML5 rules and CSS, and for some reason my text (which has mostly been cut as irrelevant here) is wrapping around my images. What I want is two columns side by side, with the images centered and the text underneath them.

Here's my code:

```
<section>
    <h1>The Beasts</h1>

    <p>text here</p>

    <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="flexside">

            <figure class"beast"><img src="images/tonka.jpg" alt="Tonka, the old man." /></figure>
            <p>text here</p>

            <p>text here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flexside">

            <figure class="beast2"><img src="images/storm.jpg" alt="Storm, our Gangster Princess" /></figure>               
            <p>text here</p>

            <p>text here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flexside">

            <figure class="beast"><img class="cats" src="images/banshee.jpg" alt="Deafbat aka Banshee" /></figure>

            <p>text here</p>

            <p>text here</p>

            <p>text here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flexside">  

            <figure class="beast2"><img class="cats" src="images/squiggle.jpg" alt="Mr Squiggle, the man from the Moon." /></figure>

            <p>text here</p>

            <p>text here</p>

            <p>text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="images/kittens.jpg" alt="The kittens, Rumple and Mungo." />
    <p>text here</p>

    <p>text here</p>

    <p>text here.</p>

    <p>text here</p>
</section>
```

And here’s the CSS:

```
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexside {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

figure.beast {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

figure.beast2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img.cats {
  height: 233px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: do u want both images and text centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `flexbox` for the container class here, you can use flex itself to center the inner boxes using:

```
.flexside {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

For the images to contain the width of the boxes use:

```
img {
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

---

Also remove the `margin: auto` from `.figure .beast` and `.figure .beast2`. See demo below:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexside {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
img{
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
}
p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
figure.beast {
  text-align: center;
}
figure.beast2 {
  display: block;
}
img.cats {
  height: 233px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>The Beasts</h1>

  <p>text here</p>

  <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="flexside">

      <figure class "beast">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Tonka, the old man." />
      </figure>
      <p>text here</p>

      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexside">

      <figure class="beast2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Storm, our Gangster Princess" />
      </figure>
      <p>text here</p>

      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexside">

      <figure class="beast">
        <img class="cats" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Deafbat aka Banshee" />
      </figure>

      <p>text here</p>

      <p>text here</p>

      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexside">

      <figure class="beast2">
        <img class="cats" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Mr Squiggle, the man from the Moon." />
      </figure>

      <p>text here</p>

      <p>text here</p>

      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="The kittens, Rumple and Mungo." />
  <p>text here</p>

  <p>text here</p>

  <p>text here.</p>

  <p>text here</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi kukkuz, thank you so much for helping out with this. I made a couple of tweaks to what you wrote after I pasted it in to see how it looked but it worked perfectly :) I'm not too familiar with flexboxes since I haven't coded CSS in a very long time, but they're powerful little tools. Wow! (Sorry about the delay, had to work >.<)